# how to get all change numbers from sync - p4python

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I periodically get a p4 sync and want to know what actually got synced.
So I get the return from `p4.run_sync` which is a list of dicts per change (as far as I understood)

```
sync = p4.run_sync()
```

when I print the keys it looks like that:

```
sync dict Nr: 0 --------------
* totalFileSize
* rev
* totalFileCount
* clientFile
* fileSize
* action
* depotFile
* change
sync dict Nr: 1 --------------
* action
* clientFile
* rev
* depotFile
* fileSize
sync dict Nr: 2 --------------
* action
* clientFile
* rev
* depotFile
* fileSize
```

So only in the **first** dict there is a **change** number!

How do I get the others? I currently browse the `depotFiles` of the other dicts and get the headChange from `p4.fstat`.. but this seems quite hacky...

I'd actually like each change number that was synced to fetch a describe right away.

Or is there a more proper way todo this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `p4.run_sync()` or any of the `p4.run_COMMAND()` returns a list and not a dict. Each element of the list could be either a dict or a string depending on the perforce server support and whether you disabled tagged or not.

From the documentation of the [`p4.run`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html#1122735):

```
Whether the elements of the array are strings or dictionaries depends on
(a) server support for tagged output for the command, and
(b) whether tagged output was disabled by calling p4.tagged = False.
```

- When you run a `p4.run_sync()` (the equivalent of `p4 sync ...`), you're going to get the latest for all the files under that directory.
- The first file in the list contains the latest change number which perforce synced to and it need not be the change at which that file was modified.
- The change number just corresponds to the latest change under that directory.
- The remaining files in the list omit this redundant information. This is the reason, the key `change` is not part of the other dicts in the list of files.

For each file you get the revision number in the `rev` key which combined with the full perforce path in `depotFile` corresponds to a unique version of the file in the repository (for example `//depot/branch1/dir1/file1#4`).

You could just make use of this information as follows with the `fstat`. (No, this is not a hacky way, this is the correct way of fetching the change number corresponding to a particular file and revision).

```
>>> result = p4.run_fstat("//depot/branch1/dir1/file1#4")
>>> print result[0]['headChange']
12345
```

This indicates that revision 4 of `//depot/branch1/dir1/file1` came as part of change `12345`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You could have shortened the answer to:
* no its list of dicts `per file` in the sync and
* append the `rev` nr to your fstat query.